# How to align Ionic v3 (3.9.1) navBar back button to the right?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have already read just too many questions and answers from too many websites, and all of them are either for Ionic 1, or for buttons other than the navBar buttons.

Just to be clear, I'm talking about the back button that comes with the navBar.

Comment: add CSS float: right or just add text-end in button.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, they're aligned with this code:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      BLA BLA BLA 
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Hope it's what you're looking.

Comment: Ion-back-button is an API for older versions of ionic, not v3. I Can't use that.

Comment: I got confused then. It didn't exist on ionic 3, only now on 4.